# texture painting rams horns

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have been trying to texture paint a set of horns from this reference that as you can see look as if they have been painted badly with a paintbrush[image: ram's head with painted horns]. I have experimented with using a brush stroke image as a texture mask with little success as i've found it very had to get continuous strokes around the shape. Any suggestions of how I might approach this would be much appreciated

Comment: yes doing it with a texture used as Stencil to make a mask seems the good idea, what do you mean by "very hard to get continuous strokes around the shape"?

Comment: I would suggest to paint on the image rather than the model. Should be easier to produce a continous stroke there.

Comment: Perhaps you need to think about painting a separate mask first to open up the holes there, and then also think about painting a bump map to give the impression of the paint strokes. Then you can use an image as your color layer with the gradation to help sell it as brush strokes from a paint brush.

Comment: As I understand it using an image to the texture mask as opposed to an image as the texture is akin to using a textured brush. I used this approach  because it appears the horns are the same plaster material as the skull that have been painted. The problem is that using this method it is difficult to follow the cylindrical topology with my stroke from my viewport. I will try Frederik’s suggestion to paint on the 2D image and then touch up the seam after. Craig I didn’t understand your suggestion to paint a separate mask to open up the holes first? Bump map for brush strokes makes sense.